# Text file read/write in Unity for iOS

Tags: c#, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get text file read/write access at Unity for iOs project.
What I did was

```
        //Read
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Application.persistentDataPath + "/record.txt"); 
        string record = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        string[] records = record.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        firstname = records [0]; lastname = records [1]; loginName = records [2]; password = records [3];
        reader.Close();
        email.transform.GetComponent<InputField> ().text = loginName;
        pwd.transform.GetComponent<InputField> ().text = password;


        //Write

        File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/record.txt", String.Empty);
        //File.Create (Application.persistentDataPath + "/record.txt").Close ();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter (Application.persistentDataPath + "/record.txt", true);
        writer.WriteLine (Login.firstname + " " + Login.lastname + " " + Login.loginName + " " + Login.password);
        writer.Close ();
```

Then I include the file to Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources, so the file is inside the project.
But when I run the app inside the device, I can't read file and got message as

```
IsolatedStorageException: Could not find file "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D48E51C7-F2EE-48CF-9B84-6602CE135EBC/Documents/record.txt".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: You are reading before writing the file. If the file is not yet there, you will get an exception...Is the file already in your project or are you creating it from script?

Comment: @Programmer The file is there. Read, write are just to show how I did.

Comment: Ok but how did it get there? You created it by code or through Editor?

Comment: I just make a text file and included into Resources inside unity. It works in Unity as `StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter ("Assets/Resources/record.txt", true);`.Just doesn't work on iPhone. For Xcode project, I included the file Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.

Comment: The resources folder in Assets/Resources?

Comment: The persistent data path != Resources folder

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

Putting text file in Resources folder is not a good practice because Unity will always try to serialize everything you  put in that folder at build time. Instead copy your file into StreamingAssets folder then use

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath,"text.txt"));
```

This will work just fine. Note : for files that you don't want Unity to touch at build time put them in StreamingAssets.